# Sanitizing user input when inserting nested fields with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection filled with structures that look like this:

```js
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
  "sections": {
      "Some Cool Section" : {
        "sources" : ["source1", "source2", "source3"]
      }
      "An Awesome Section" : {
        "sources" : ["source1", "source2", "source3"]
      }
   },
  "username": "boatzart"
}
```

I need to allow users to add new "sections" arbitrarily, so using pymongo I can add sections like so:

```py
userid = bson.ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
sectionname = getUnsafeUserInput()
mongo.db.userprofiles.update({'_id' : userid},
  { '$set' : { 'sections.'+sectionname: { 'sources': []} } }
    )
```

Because sectionname comes from unsafe user input, some malicious user can really mess up the database by putting things like periods in their section name.  I can easily just scrub out non alpha-numeric characters, but I sense that there should be a better way to do this.

Is there a better way to insert nested fields into an existing document that won't require me to scrub the contents?

If not, then what characters should I deem unsafe? All non alpha-numerics? Only periods? Periods, and dollar signs?

Comment: Why don't you just forbid characters `[^\w- ]`?  Seems like a fine solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rework the schema, it should work cleaner to treat those user-defined section names as values instead of keys:

```js
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "sections": [{
        "name": "Some Cool Section",
        "sources" : ["source1", "source2", "source3"]
      }, {
        "name": "An Awesome Section",
        "sources" : ["source1", "source2", "source3"]
      }
  ],
  "username": "boatzart"
}
```

Using dynamic key names is rarely a good idea as it makes querying and updating messy.

Comment: Much better! I just had to learn to embrace the positional operator.